# Jersey: disable default JSON provider

Tags: java, jersey, jackson, jersey-2.0

i am using Jersey 2.17, JSON and automatic feature discovery.

I have my custom JSON Provider extending `JacksonJsonProvider`. It's annotated with `@Provider` and automatically registerd, same as default one that comes with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I want to disable/exclude default one without giving up on feature scanning/manually registering everything.

Only solution I've came up with is `@Priority(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` to make sure my provider have higher priority, but I don't like  the idea of relying on priority.

tried `jersey.config.disableJsonProcessing` but it does not seem to change anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, so the Jackson feature is wrapped in an [auto-discoverable](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.autodiscoverable), so it's automatically registered. There a a couple options I see.

#### *You Could...*

Disable the auto discovery feature with the property

```
CommonProperties.FEATURE_AUTO_DISCOVERY_DISABLE
- or -
"jersey.config.disableAutoDiscovery"
```

The only thing with this is that any other feature that you would expect to be registered automatically (which are also auto discovered) will need to be registered again. (There aren't many features that are auto-discovered, so it might not be that big of a problem to disable it, if any).

#### *You Could...*

Not use `jersey-media-json-jackson` and instead use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

`jersey-media-json-jackson` actually uses that provider, it doesn't actually provide any of it's own Jackson functionality. All it does really is register the MBR, MBW, and ExceptionMapper, and also wrap it in the auto-discoverable. The `JacksonJsonProvider` or `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` you extended is there. You may also want to register the `JsonParseExceptionMapper` and `JsonMappingExceptionMapper`.

#### *Also...*

Not sure why you are extending the `JacksonJsonProvider`, but if it's just to register your own `ObjectMapper`, the more common approach is to configure it in a [`ContextResolver`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson)