# Registering JacksonJsonProvider with ObjectMapper + JavaTimeModule to Jersey 2 Client

Tags: java, jackson, jersey-2.0, jsr310

I'm trying to marshal response containing ISO formatted timestamp like that:

```
{
...
    "time" : "2014-07-02T04:00:00.000000Z"
...
}
```

into `ZonedDateTime` field in my domain model object. Eventually it works if I use solution that is commented in following snippet.There are many similar questions on SO but I would like to get a specific answer
 what is wrong with  another approach which uses `JacksonJsonProvider` with `ObjectMapper + JavaTimeModule`?

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        JacksonJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJsonProvider(mapper);
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
//                .register(new ObjectMapperContextResolver(){
//                    @Override
//                    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
//                        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
//                        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
//                        return mapper;
//                    }
//                })
                .register(provider)
                .register(JacksonFeature.class)
                .build();
```

Error I get:

```
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.time.ZonedDateTime: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2017-02-24T20:46:05.000000Z')
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@53941c2f
```

Project dependencies are:

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.8.7'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.8.7'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.7'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.7'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.7'
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.25.1'
```

*edit*

Deserialization happens in here:

```
CandlesResponse<BidAskCandle> candlesResponse = webTarget.request()
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,"Bearer "+token)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .get(new GenericType<CandlesResponse<BidAskCandle>>(){});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Eventually it works if I use solution that is commented in following snippet.

First of all, you are missing a dependency in your list, that you also have, which is the problem.

`jersey-media-json-jackson`

This module depends on the native Jackson module that has the `JacksonJsonProvider`. When you register the `JacksonFeature` (that comes with `jersey-media-json-jackson`), it registers its own `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`, which seems to take precedence over any that you provide.

When you use the `ContextResolver`, the `JacksonJsonProvider` actually looks-up that `ContextResolver` and uses it to resolve the `ObjectMapper`. That's why it works. Whether you used the `JacksonFeature` or registered your own `JacksonJsonProvider` (without configuring an `ObjectMapper` for it) the `ContextResovler` would work.

Another thing about the `jersey-media-json-jackson` module, it that it participates in Jersey's [auto-discoverable](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.autodiscoverable) mechanism, which registers it's `JacksonFeature`. So even if you didn't explicitly register it, it would still be registered. The only ways to avoid it being registered are to:

1. Disable the auto-discovery (as mention in the [previous link](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.autodiscoverable))<sup>1</sup>
2. Don't use the `jersey-media-json-jackson`. Just use the Jackson native module `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider`. Thing about this though is that, the `jersey-media-json-jackson` adds a couple features on top of the  the native module, so you would lose those.
3. Haven't tested, but it seems that if you use `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` instead of `JacksonJsonProvider`, it might work. If you look at the [source for the `JacksonFeature`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.25.1/media/json-jackson/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature.java#L85), you will see that it checks for an already registered `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`. If there is one, it won't register it's own.

   The one thing I'm not sure about with this is the auto-discoverable. The order in which it is registered, if it will affect whether or not it catches your registered `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`. Something you can test out.

---

#### Footnotes

<sub>1. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30281912/2587435)</sub>

Comment: I chose option with `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` as it looks more straightforward and doesn't involve extra dependencies. It works.

Comment: the previous link turns out to be a hanging reference by now

Comment: @inxoy I just fixed it. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: The "disable the auto-discovery" link is dead now since Jersey changed their pages, suggest you link to this question instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30278303/jersey-disable-default-json-provider

Answer (score 8):

From my pet project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>

public WebTarget getTarget(URI uri) {
    Client client = ClientBuilder
            .newClient()
            .register(JacksonConfig.class);
    return client.target(uri);
}
```

where

```
@Provider
public class JacksonConfig implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JacksonConfig() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> aClass) {
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Jackson configuration looks fine, I tried the following and was able to deserialize the value:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        Model model = mapper.readValue("{\"time\" : \"2014-07-02T04:00:00.000000Z\"}", Model.class);
        System.out.println(model.getTime());
    }

}

class Model{
    private ZonedDateTime time;

    public ZonedDateTime getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(ZonedDateTime time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

I can reproduce it by commenting out `mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());`. So, it looks like jersey client is not using custom `mapper` instance. Could you try configuring it as described [here](http://code-willy.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/jersey-client-with-customize-json.html).

Comment: Tried, no change :(

Comment: Do you mean this? `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()); JacksonJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJsonProvider(); provider.setMapper(mapper); ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig(provider); Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);` However this doesn't work either.

Comment: Could you post the code that performs the deserialization?